# How to filter HTML data with Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to filter the labels of a scraper that I'm doing but I've not been able to find the way in which I can filter the data that I need. The code is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = input("Url a scrapear: ")

pagina = requests.get(url)

elementos = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content, 'html.parser')

productos = elementos.find_all('div', class_='picture')

enlaces = pd.DataFrame(productos)

print(productos)
```

I need to extract the href data from all the  tags that are inside the specified . Any idea how to do it? Because I've tried everything I could think of and I can't find a solution. This is the last code I've try, but it didn't work with any parameter I use to filter href data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "https://www.plasticosur.com/almacenaje-y-conservacion-#/isFilters=1&pageSize=36&viewMode=grid&orderBy=15&pageNumber=1"

pagina = requests.get(url)

elementos = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content, 'html.parser')

productos = elementos.find_all('div', class_='picture')
out_dict = {}
for div in elementos.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'picture'}):
    out_dict[div.find('a')['href']] = div.find('img')['src']


print(out_dict)
```

Comment: I already try it, but itn't work cuz it can't detec the attribute find_all exist. This is the error I see:

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Give me an example URL

Comment: https://www.plasticosur.com/almacenaje-y-conservacion-#/isFilters=1&pageSize=36&viewMode=grid&orderBy=15&pageNumber=1

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup4==4.10.0 FYI, and have edited answer

Comment: That really help a lot dude. Thank you! With that I can do what I want :D